# Sequential SVM in Scikit

Tags: python, scikit-learn, svm, sequential

I am using scikit in python to classify the data using SVM. The data has 3 features. Two of them are integer values and one of them is a sequence of sensor values. One of the features is label. how can i define a feature as a sequence? An example of given sequence is (M1=1 , M2=0 , M3=1). i have written the below code but does not work.

```
data = np.empty((5, 2))
target = np.empty((5,), dtype=np.int)
for i in range(5):
    data[i] = np.asarray( ([[i,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,1,1,0] ,[1,1,1,0,0]] , [i] ))
    target[i] = np.asarray(i%2, dtype=np.int)
h = .02 
C = 1.0  # SVM regularization parameter
svc = svm.SVC(kernel='linear', C=C).fit(data, target)
rbf_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='rbf', gamma=0.7, C=C).fit(data, target)
poly_svc = svm.SVC(kernel='poly', degree=3, C=C).fit(data, target)
lin_svc = svm.LinearSVC(C=C).fit(data, target)
```

The error is:

```
data[i] = np.asarray( ([[i,1,1,1,1] , [1,1,1,1,0] ,[1,1,1,0,0]] , [i] ))#,       dtype=np.l)
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What is your idea to solve this problem and classify sequence data using SVM?

Comment: This is a question about feature engineering, not programming. It just so happens that you _also_ can't have arrays of sequences in Numpy, which is the source of the error you see, but that's immaterial here. In general an SVM requires a _matrix_ of numerical features as input. Turning sequences into SVM-compatible features will require some thinking on your part. If you can rephrase the question to that end, I would encourage you to delete it here and re-ask on datascience.stackexchange.com

Comment: I agree with ssdecontrol: represent your sequences as several additional features. If some sequences have variable length then you should figure out which of them are skipped for your concrete objects (rows). Skipped features could be replaced with specific value *or* you can not take into consideration objects with skipped data if their part is small. However skipping can make your potential model worse if the fact element's absence in the sequences is important.

Comment: Thanks ssdecontrol and sergzach. I asked my question in datascience.stackexchange.com too. I have variation in sentence length. and i can not give some values to skipped ones.